Error saving a Business Process in Naemon/Thruk
I'm using the Business Process plugin within Naemon/Thruk, and have previously been able to edit/save the processes successfully.  More recently - and I don't know if it's a result of patches applied to my system, I'm now getting an error when trying to save a business process.

The only additional thing I see in my thruk.log file is
Naemon: 491: failed to connect - failed to connect to localhost:7003: Connection refused. at /usr/share/thruk/lib/Thruk/Backend/Manager.pm line 1598

I'm not really sure where to start troubleshooting this issue - if anybody has any tips, I'd appreciate the help.  Thanks

have you considered opening an issue for thruk or naemon?

I'm not sure if it's the right place to do so, but I submitted a new issue here https://github.com/naemon/naemon-core/issues/460
